# JML - OpenJML with Extended Static Checking - Array Example

Tags: java, jml, openjml

I just started to use OpenJML, here my code and my JML warning:

Code :

```
//@ requires myArray != null ;
//@ ensures myArray == \old(myArray) ;
//@ signals ( MathLibException ) myArray.size() == 1 ;
public ArrayList<Integer> ExceptionTest1 (ArrayList<Integer> myArray) throws MathLibException
{
    if ( myArray.size() == 1  )
    {
        throw new MathLibException();
    }
    else
        return arraylist;
}
```

JML warnings :

[image: JML warnings]

I don't understand why the exceptional post condition can't be established.

Thank you, for your help

Answer (score 0):

Problem resolved,

my exception wasn't pure, with this code, it is working :

```
    public /*@ pure @*/ MathLibException() {
}
```